# How to check all checkboxes inside an specific table with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many dinamic tables, each one creates a dinamic master checkbox inside an **input** and several checkboxes inside **td**'s (each one has a different ID). The idea is once I check or uncheck the master checkbox, every checkbox inside **THAT** specific table check/uncheck. (Some checkboxes inside table are previously check or uncheck from DDBB)

Here is a simple HTML trying to emulate what I want to do:

```js
function testing() {

  if ($("#masterSwitch1").prop("checked") == true) {
    $('table[id^="table1"]').each(function() {
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').attr("checked");
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').prop("checked", true);
    });
  } else {
    $('table[id^="table1"]').each(function() {
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').removeAttr("checked");
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').prop("checked", false);
    });
  }

  if ($("#masterSwitch2").prop("checked") == true) {
    $('table[id^="table2"]').each(function() {
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').attr("checked");
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').prop("checked", true);
    });
  } else {
    $('table[id^="table2"]').each(function() {
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').removeAttr("checked");
      $('td[class^="clientAct"]').prop("checked", false);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="testing()" id="masterSwitch1"> Try me!
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="testing()" id="masterSwitch2"> Try me 2!
<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for your help. I really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: when making dynamic table, add some unique identifier that you will pass to testing function, it it works only with its own table. This way, you will end up having multiple objects with same id

Answer (score 2):

> This code is worked it,so you can try this..!

```js
$(".testing").on("change",function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var tableID = $(this).data('id');

  if($('#'+id+'').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('#'+tableID+'').find('.clientAct').attr("checked", true);
      $('#'+tableID+'').find('.clientEje').attr("checked", true);
  } else {
      $('#'+tableID+'').find('.clientAct').attr("checked", false);
      $('#'+tableID+'').find('.clientEje').attr("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="testing" id="masterSwitch1" data-id="table1"> Try me!
<table id="table1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Table 1</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Last Name</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="testing" id="masterSwitch2" data-id="table2"> Try me 2!
<table id="table2">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Table 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Name 2</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Last Name 2</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```js
$("#masterSwitch1").on("change", function(){
  

  if($("#masterSwitch1").is(':checked')){
    $('#table1 input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var checkbox=$(this);
        checkbox.prop("checked",true)
    });
  }else{
    $('#table1 input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var checkbox=$(this);
        checkbox.prop("checked",false)
    });
  }
})

$("#masterSwitch2").on("change", function(){
  

  if($("#masterSwitch2").is(':checked')){
    $('#table2 input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var checkbox=$(this);
        checkbox.prop("checked",true)
    });
  }else{
    $('#table2 input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var checkbox=$(this);
        checkbox.prop("checked",false)
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  id="masterSwitch1"> Try me!
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"  id="masterSwitch2"> Try me 2!
<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you could do as below, you do need to use `each` loop

Also you have use id as `id="s2"` which is duplicated, you should use unique id in document.

```js
function testing() {

if( $("#masterSwitch1").prop("checked") == true) {
    
    $('#table1').find('.clientAct').attr("checked", true);
} else {
    $('#table1').find('.clientAct').attr("checked", false);
}

if( $("#masterSwitch2").prop("checked") == true) {
    
    $('#table2').find('.clientAct').attr("checked", true);
} else {
    
    $('#table2').find('.clientAct').attr("checked", false);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="testing()" id="masterSwitch1"> Try me!
<table id="table1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Table 1</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Last Name</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="testing()" id="masterSwitch2"> Try me 2!
<table id="table2">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Table 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Name 2</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s1"></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s2" checked></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Last Name 2</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientAct" id="s3" checked></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="clientEje" id="s4"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[id*="masterSwitch"]').click(function (e) {
        var isChecked = $(e.target).prop('checked');
        $(e.target).next().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', isChecked);
    });
});
```

Or in case these blocks (checkbox and table) are dynamically added to the view, you can use your test function this way.
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="testing(this)" id="masterSwitch1">
```

JS:

```
function testing(checkbox) {
    var isChecked = $(checkbox).prop('checked');
    $(checkbox).next().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', isChecked);
}
```